# Overloading free() so my program use mine instead of the system's

Tags: c, linux, malloc, free

I need to recode the `free()` func for educational purpose and it must be named `free()` also.

When i rename my function `myfree()` it work flawlessly but when i name it `free()` the program don't know if he need to use mine or the system's so the program just `Segmentation fault(core dumped)` even if i don't call my free (just the declaration of another `free()` func seem to crash it)

so how can i tell the compiler to use mine instead of the system's ?

thanks you in advance.

EDIT : Linux operating system

Comment: Which OS are we talking about? Linux?

Comment: `segmentation fault` is a runtime error.  If the compiler didn't know which to use it would be a compile time error... you would not have a compiled binary to run. The C language does not include overloading because function names are not mangled (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) in C.Can you show how you're attempting this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you have three options that I can see

- Redirect it during compile time, for example using `#define` as @Mohamed suggests.
- Change it at runtime using [LD_PRELOAD](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7795).
- Modify the existing malloc/free using [malloc hooks](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html).

Comment: Redefining `free` is undefined behavior. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14770384/912144).

Comment: @Shahbaz Agreed, using `#define` to change system behavior is probably not the most portable idea.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using GCC, you can use the compiler to help you. When you compile, include this on your link line: `-Xlinker --wrap=free`. This will redirect all calls to `free()` to use `__wrap_free()`, which you must provide. If you wish to call the original `free()` function, it's still there but renamed; you can call `__real_free()`.

This will capture pre-compiled libraries you link against, something a macro cannot do (but LD_PRELOAD can).

Answer (score 1):

use macros for that: to force program to use your `myfree()` function:

```
#define free(X) myfree(X)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (not the safest) way is to `#define free myfree` so the preprocessor will replace all calls from *free()* to *myfree()*. Another, more safe approach, would be create a normal function called *free()* and do not include libraries, that also contain *free()* function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a standard way, I'm afraid it doesn't exist. Redefining standard library names is undefined behavior.

C11, 7.1.3.2:

> ... If the program declares or defines an identifier in a
>      context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved
>       identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.

In 7.1.4, there are is a long explanation of how the library may define a macro *with the same name as the function* and how to bypass that macro. There is no indication of how a user may override a standard library function.

You can also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14770384/912144) for more information.

Non standard ways are of course always possible as you can find in other answers.