# Is it undefined behavior to redefine a standard name?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

It's easy to reason how such a code would work:

```
#include <string.h>

#define strcmp my_strcmp

int my_strcmp(const char *, const char *)

...
strcmp(str1, str2);
...
```

But this question is whether this is technically correct or not.

From C11:

7.1.3.1 (on reserved names):

> ...
>
> - Each macro name in any of the following subclauses (including the future library
>     directions) is reserved for use as specified if any of its associated headers is included;
>     unless explicitly stated otherwise (see 7.1.4).
> - All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the
>     future library directions) and errno are always reserved for use as identifiers with
>     external linkage.<sup>184</sup>)
> - Each identifier with file scope listed in any of the following subclauses (including the
>     future library directions) is reserved for use as a macro name and as an identifier with
>     file scope in the same name space if any of its associated headers is included.
>
> <sup>184</sup> The list of reserved identifiers with external linkage includes math_errhandling, setjmp, va_copy, and va_end.

So this means that `strcmp` is a reserved word because `string.h` is included.

7.1.3.2:

> ... If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.

Now this seems to say redefining `strcmp` is undefined behavior, except it is somehow allowed in 7.1.4.

The possibly relevant contents of 7.1.4 are:

7.1.4.1:

> ... Any function declared in a header may be additionally implemented as a function-like macro defined in the header, so if a library function is declared explicitly when its header is included, one of the techniques shown below can be used to ensure the declaration is not affected by such a macro. Any macro definition of a function can be suppressed locally by enclosing the name of the function in parentheses, because the name is then not followed by the left parenthesis that indicates expansion of a macro function name. For the same syntactic reason, it is permitted to take the address of a library function even if it is also defined as a macro.<sup>185</sup>) The use of #undef to remove any macro definition will also ensure that an actual function is referred to. ...
>
> <sup>185</sup> This means that an implementation shall provide an actual function for each library function, even if it also provides a macro for that function.

7.1.4.2:

> Provided that a library function can be declared without reference to any type defined in a header, it is also permissible to declare the function and use it without including its
>   associated header.

The rest of the clauses are irrelevant. I don't see what 7.1.3.2 refers to as "as allowed by 7.1.4", except the definition of the library function *in the same header as the function, i.e. the standard header*, as a macro.

In summary, is the code above techincally undefined behavior? How about if `string.h` was not included?

Comment: This question is based on a false premise. The dispute that arose [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14728064/298225) was not whether defining a reserved identifier was undefined by C but whether it could be defined by other means and whether a person could do it (that is, whether, in some circumstances, a person could make productive use of behavior of a C implementation that was not defined by the C standard).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least one reason why it's UB is that `string.h` can introduce macros. For internal implementation reasons, those macros might have been written on the assumption that `strcmp` is the "real" strcmp function. If you define `strcmp` to be something else and then use those macros, `strcmp` will expand to `my_strcmp` in the macros, with unexpected consequences.

Rather than try to work out exactly what code would be OK in the `...` and what would not, the standard puts an early stop to your shenanigans.

Also note that aside from the fact that the standard flat-out forbids it, your `#define strcmp my_strcmp` might be a macro re-definition, because `string.h` is permitted to do `#define strcmp __strcmp` or whatever. So on some conforming implementations your code is ill-formed.

Comment: That was what I thought too. How about if `string.h` is _not_ included?

Comment: @Shahbaz: `strcmp` is a bit of a special case because it's covered by the names reserved for future directions (anything starting with `str`), so I think it's probably reserved if you include *any* standard header. Generally, though, in C if you don't include a standard header then the names it defines are not reserved as macros/identifiers, but they are still all reserved for external linkage. There are some names that the standard says are defined by more than one header.

Comment: Right. Thanks for the answer. I had said it's undefined behavior in [an answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14728064/912144) but it didn't seem clear to others. I asked to make sure.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Eric is correct there that just because something is UB doesn't mean "you can't do it". It means that the standard doesn't give your program an inalienable right to do it. He was not saying that it's not undefined behavior, he was saying it's not necessarily true that you can't do it. If you're writing portable code it amounts to much the same thing, you wouldn't want to do anything that only certain implementations guarantee will work. If you're writing non-portable code then your system documentation is as valid as the standard.

Answer (score 6):

A program that declares or defines reserved identifiers is not strictly conforming (C 2011 4 5) but may be conforming (C 2011 4 7).

The [dispute out of which this question arose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14728064/298225) was not about whether declaring or defining a reserved identifier is behavior that is undefined by C but whether the behavior may be defined by other means, such as documentation for a specific C implementation, and whether or not a program author could do it.

Some people treat “undefined behavior” as meaning “You may not do this.” This is an incorrect interpretation of “undefined behavior.” Undefined behavior is not something the standard requires you to avoid; it is something the C standard does not help you with.

The C standard explicitly states that it imposes **no requirements** on undefined behavior. In particular, this means there is no requirement that you may not do it and no requirement that another specification may not define the behavior. Nearly every practical program uses behavior that the C standard does not define, when it makes system calls defined by the operating system documentation or library calls defined by the library documentation or relies on the formats of data types defined by the specific C implementation it is designed for.

In C, “undefined behavior” is merely the end of the rules set by the C standard. It is an open field that you can navigate using other means and not a wall that blocks your progress.

Comment: The C Standard also imposes no judgment about whether quality implementations intended for various purposes *should* define various behaviors beyond those mandated by the Standard, nor whether an implementation can be suitable for any particular purpose [or any purpose whatsoever] without doing so.  For example, a low-quality-but-conforming implementation could impose a limit on the number of times the letter "i" appears in a source text, and behave in essentially arbitrary fashion if a program exceeds that limit.  A really low-quality implementation could set that limit as low as 0...

Comment: ...if the way it behaves when that limit is exceeded would coincide with the behavior of some particular contrived program which exercises all the limits in the Translation Limits section of the Standard.  After all, feeding the latter "One Program" into the implementation would yield behavior indistinguishable from "processing" it in conforming fashion.  Of course, quality implementations shouldn't do that, but the point is that the Standard makes no attempt for forbid all the ways that low-quality implementation might make themselves useless (or less useful than they otherwise could be).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is undefined behaviour. It is LIKELY that it will work, but you can't know for sure.

I believe the reason for this is to allow the compiler to have builtin knowledge of how `str` functions work. And of course, `strcmp` may already be a macro of `memcmp(s1, s2, strlen(s1))` or something like that [I'm not saying that's how it is, just that COULD be.

I don't believe "not including string.h" actually helps.

I would suggest that you do a search and replace of `strcmp` with `my_strcmp` in the source. You can always go the other way around and use `#define my_strcmp(s1, s2) strcmp(s1, s2)` should you wish to "go back".

Comment: It's not my code. I [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14728064/912144) to another question that this is undefined behavior, and I was met with resistance. That's why asked to make sure.

Comment: Ok, so you may want to advice that "doing it the other way around" will work!