# Porting user space code to kernel space

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, rtai

I have a big system written mostly in C that was running in user space up till now. Now I need to compile the code as a kernel module. For that, afaik, I should at least rewrite the code and replace functions as `malloc`, `calloc`, `free`, `printf` with their kernel equivalents, because those are solely user-space functions. The problem is, however, that I don't have the source code to some custom-made libraries used in the system, and those libraries call `malloc` etc. inside their functions. So, basically, I might need to reimplement the whole library.

Now the question: will it be a really dirty hack, if I'd write my own implementation of `malloc` as a wrapper around `kmalloc`, something like this:

```
void *malloc(size_t size) {
    return kmalloc(size, GFP_USER);
}
```

Then link this implementation to the system code, which will eliminate all the *Unknown symbol in module* errors.

Actually I thought that this would be a common problem and someone would have already written such a kmalloc wrapper, but I've been googling for a couple of days now and found nothing useful.

EDIT: The reason for doing this is that the system I'm talking about was a realtime application running on VxWorks realtime OS and now we want to port it to be used on Linux RTAI, where the apps mostly run in kernel space. But I guess there is a possibility to have real-time in user space as well, so, I should probably do as Mike suggested and separate the code into kernel and user-space parts and communicate between them with shared memory.

Comment: I just saw [this hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14728092/912144) for gcc which may be useful to you.

Comment: Normally people try to move things out from the kernel, instead of the other way around. My personal experience is that if you think you're needing to make a kernel module of your program, then you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg he probably got to this thinking it will be faster in kernel space

Comment: @Ulterior - of course the more stuff you shove in the kernel the less deterministic it becomes.

Comment: I agree with Joachim Pileborg. Moving a big application into kernel space is a huge mistake. I'll rather suggest profiling it wisely, and only optimize the few (if any) significant bottlenecks around some syscalls.

Comment: @eris, can you explain what are your motives for this? There may be a better way.

Comment: You're asking a question about "how", which anyone with kernel experience will respond to with "why?".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've never seen this done before. I did have to do something similar at a previous job (in our phones, for power savings reasons, we had to port a portion of code from user space from the kernel) but that's how I did it.. I took *a portion* of the code and moved it, and a small portion at that.

When I did it I changed the user space calls to kernel calls because of a number of reasons two primary ones:

1. It was less confusing that way (others looking at the code didn't have to wonder why I was calling "malloc" from the kernel)
2. `malloc` and `kmalloc` don't work exactly the same. What I mean by that is

   2a. `kmalloc` takes a `flags` parameter, in your example above you hardcoded it. What if you decide later that you want to change it in some places and not others? (assuming you have a number of different places where you get dynamic memory).

   2b. `kmalloc` doesn't give you memory in the same way as `malloc`. `malloc()` will give you the number of bytes you pass in as `size_t size`. `kmalloc()` on the other hand, is in the kernel and thus is dealing with the physical memory of the system, which is available only in page-sized chunks; thus when you call `kmalloc()` you are going to get only certain predefined, fixed-size byte arrays. if you're not aware of this, you might ask for just *over* a particular chunk and thus get much more memory than you need... a direct port of your code won't protect you from that.

   2c. The header files have to change too. Obviously you can't include `<stdlib.h>` in the kernel, so just because you "wrapped" the malloc call, you still have to go around replacing header files.

quick example of my point in 2b above:

```
void * stuff;
stuff = kmalloc(1,GFP_KERNEL);
printk("I got: %zu bytes of memory\n", ksize(stuff));
kfree(stuff);
```

To show the actual amount of memory allocated:

```
[90144.702588] I got: 32 bytes of memory
```

---

anyway... technically, how you describe it, should work fine. Both take a `size_t` and return a `void *` so it should work; but be aware that the more code you move into the kernel the less deterministic things become, and that `malloc()`<=>`kmalloc()` isn't as 1:1 as it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to make my RTAI code compilable in both user and kernel spaces (as well as working with POSIX), I have developed [URT](https://github.com/ShabbyX/URT) which essentially does what you are asking. It's a lightweight abstraction level over real-time systems (and even over the inconsistent user-space vs kernel-space RTAI functions).